# How to scrape all hyperlinks correspoding to matches details from flashscore?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape hyperlinks to matches from flashscore page.

For example if I go to https://www.flashscore.com/football/france/ligue-1-2021-2022/results/ I have list of matches and results and I want to get links to all match details that are in this page, so to get link: https://www.flashscore.com/match/K2ED4alK/#/match-summary/match-summary and then next link which is https://www.flashscore.com/match/EPDH3J3Q/#/match-summary/match-summary .

I tried to get this data using such code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/football/france/ligue-1-2022-2023/results/'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

But it works just for bars at the top and on the left side but I cannot get matches hyperlinks. How can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

get the id of div first, then you can get the url as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is that the content is loaded / rendered dynamically, something that could not directly be handled via `requests` because it is not a browser and only works with the static response.

You could try to fetch the matches via API with requests or you use `selenium` to mimic browser behaviour.

The second approach can be implemented in different expansion stages. You can click on all the summary links and navigate further or you can collect the links and then call them up separately, ultimately it depends on the goal you want to achieve.

To complete the approach of @LetsScrapeData, which would not work purely with `requests` due to the circumstances described above, here is an example of collecting the links with `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = f'https://www.flashscore.com/football/france/ligue-1-2022-2023/results/'
driver.get(url)

link_list = [f'https://www.flashscore.com/match/{id.get_attribute("id").strip("g_1_")}/#/match-summary/match-summary' for id in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id^=g_1_]')))]

link_list
```

---

```
['https://www.flashscore.com/match/W0ldfU30/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/p4h0glJ6/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/W0AR993m/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/6Jt9iSmJ/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/SSs5h8YC/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/YPUjGBQJ/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/CGTfFVuQ/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/Ic6NAkls/#/match-summary/match-summary',
 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/QN9V8TI/#/match-summary/match-summary',...]
```